# Lights show through my mesh from the backside, how can I fix this?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

How can I stop the lights on the bottom of the saucer from showing through the ship?

Lights showing through body of UFO:
[image: Lights showing through body of UFO]

Comment: you are going to have to edit your question and add more info. Such as: a screen shot of your scene, description of what lights you have there, your blend etc. Are you really using cycles, or is the the blender internal render?

Comment: Yes, as it currently stands there's not nearly enough info be able to help you. How did you make those lights? Is that a composited flow effect? What render engine are you using? Please edit your question and provide more information.